# Why isn't the edit task function working for my function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a React project where I have a list of tasks that are able to be "edited". My thought process is when the user clicks edit, it fills the form with the current tasks information, and when they click "save edit" it just finds the key at which the task is at, deletes it, then creates a new task with a new key, but all of the other information is the same. However, when I try this, it does not seem to work, and just deletes the task.

Heres a snippet, hopefully it helps:

```
var saveHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.seteId(props.editTask.id); //set the old task's key
    props.setTasks([ //add our "edited" task to the list with the form info, and new key.
        ...props.tasks,
        {
          text: props.inputText,
          status: props.status,
          id: Math.random() * 1500, //I know this isnt a great way to do it
          priority: props.priority,
        },
      ]);

     props.setTasks(props.tasks.filter((el) => el.id !== props.eId)); //find old task and delete it
```

Answer (score 2):

State is updated asynchronously.

You're calling `props.setTasks` twice, but the value of `props.tasks` isn't changing between them so you are overwriting (not building on) the first state change you make.

Use a variable to store your intermediate state instead.

```
const allTasks = [ ...props.tasks, { /* etc */ } ];
const updatedTasks = allTasks.filter( /* etc */ );
props.setTasks(updatedTasks);
```

Likewise, `props.eId` won't have updated in time for `el.id !== props.eId` so use `props.editTask.id` instead of `props.eId` in your filter function.

Answer (score 0):

If i wel understand your needs this should fix your issue, testing using the old id props.editTask.id

```js
var saveHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.seteId(props.editTask.id); //set the old task's key
    props.setTasks([ //add our "edited" task to the list with the form info, and new key.
        ...props.tasks,
        {
          text: props.inputText,
          status: props.status,
          id: Math.random() * 1500, //I know this isnt a great way to do it
          priority: props.priority,
        },
      ]);

     props.setTasks(props.tasks.filter((el) => el.id !== props.editTask.id)); //find old task and delete it
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be the same as my code snippet, because Im setting the eId = props.editTask.id

Comment: props.seteId(props.editTask.id);
the eid is set in other function but if you console it just before the filter function you will found that it's the initial value in your parent state because it's not set yet in your saveHandler function